# ComboBox item not taking up horizontal space - WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Bl" MinWidth="80" x:Name="BlAssigned">
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="SName" 
                   SelectedItem="{Binding BModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   SelectedIndex="0"
                   SelectedValuePath="GId"
                   SelectedValue="{Binding B.GId, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                   MinWidth="{Binding ElementName=BlAssigned, Path=MinWidth}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource SPanelComboBox}">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
               <CompositeCollection>
                  <emodels:SModel SName="None" GId="-1"/>
                  <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.BListModels, 
                                       Source={x:Reference SDataGrid}}"/>
               </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
         </ComboBox>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding BModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                   Style="{StaticResource SPanelComboBox}">
            <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
               <CompositeCollection>
                  <emodels:SModel SName="None" GId="-1"/>
                  <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding DataContext.BListModels, 
                                       Source={x:Reference SDataGrid}}"/>
               </CompositeCollection>
            </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
         </ComboBox>
      </DataTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

SPanelComboBox XAML is as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="SPanelComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And what I'm seeing is as follows:

[image]

I have tried to fiddle with it and get it to work but no cigar.... I simply want it so that the combobox items take up all the horizontal space they can. I don't know if it's because it's a data template and it's using a composite collection or what...

Comment: You have <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/> on the itemcontainerstyle.

Comment: I think you probably want stretch on both horizontal alignments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your items to be centered horizontally always. By changing it to stretch it will have the behavior you seek.

Your ItemContainerStyle needs to look as follows:

```xml
<Style x:Key="SPanelComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/> <!-- This part is changed -->
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```